# Where is my mistake to connecting to google services?

Tags: java, android

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView email;
    TextView password;
    TextView sysAnswer;
    String[] domenArray = {"@gmail.com", "@mail.ru", "@ya.ru", "@yandex.ru", "@yahoo.ru"};
    ImageButton enter;
    ImageButton registration;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    AuthHandler aH = new AuthHandler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
        sysAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sysAnswer);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) { // слушает действия пользователя
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();               // зашел, вышел и что с этим делать
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                }
            }
        };

        findViewById(R.id.registration).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.registration) {
            aH.registration(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
            if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in) {
                aH.singing(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
                //if (aH.singingResult){
                //  Toast.makeText(this, "Успешный вход!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //} else {
                //  Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка! Включите интернет, проверьте правильность форм и попробуйте снова!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Second class.

```
public class AuthHandler {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private boolean registrationResult = false;
    private boolean singingResult = false;


    public void singing(String email, String password) {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    }

    public void registration(String email, String password){
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    registrationResult=true;
                }else {
                    registrationResult = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have compile this code, but all times my app crushed after that i click button Registration . I think, that problems with `addOnCompleteListener`, but I don't know what means executor, or how to take this method an Activity object. Can u told me my mistake. Thx for some help.

Comment: What is your log.?

Answer (score 0):

> Try to change in singing and registration method as i mention below :

```
public class AuthHandler { 

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private boolean registrationResult = false;
    private boolean singingResult = false;


    public void singing(String email, String password) {
     //   mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

          mAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    } 

    public void registration(String email, String password){
        mAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override 
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    registrationResult=true;
                }else { 
                    registrationResult = false;
                } 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
}
```